# what is dotnet counterpart for spring cloud config?

Tags: .net, spring, spring-boot, configuration, .net-core

Is there dotnet counterpart for spring cloud config? With spring cloud config you can store all your configs in a central git repository. This avoid dependency on clouds like azure.
One more interesting feature I found in spring cloud config is when you are using it with spring boot, you can hit `/refresh` endpoint to fetch updated configs without the need to restart or re-deploying application.

Googling for an equivalent solution is telling me that dotnet / dotnet core is not equally mature in terms of configuration management yet.

The closest I could get is http://steeltoe.io/docs/steeltoe-configuration/#2-0-config-server-provider

But not sure how I will be able to update configs without redeploying or restarting apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steeltoe also has the `/refresh` endpoint available: https://docs.steeltoe.io/api/v3/management/refresh.html

Were you looking for a configuration server that was also built with .NET? The Spring Cloud Config server has a lot of functionality and is pretty straight-forward to use, I would not expect a port or re-implementation of the server itself to be worth the effort.